# NSDateFormatter Convert String To Date Always Military Time

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string which represents a date stored in military time. I want to display this string in a label in 12 hr time. Here is my code snippet:

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:timeZone];  
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"Current Date: %@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
NSLog(@"Sent date: %@",[myPlanData valueForKey:@"planDate"]);
NSDate *aDate =[dateFormat dateFromString:[myPlanData valueForKey:@"planDate"]];
NSLog(@"Converted date is: %@",aDate);
NSString *planDateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:aDate];
NSLog(@"The converted date string is: %@",planDateString);
planDateLabel.text=planDateString;
```

The output is:

Current Date: 06/28/2012 10:08:48 - (so my date formatter appears correct?)

Sent date: 06/30/2012 20:47:34  - (this is the value being sent)

Converted date is: (null)    - (Here is where it breaks!)

The converted date string is: (null)

---

If i change my dateformat to

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

Everything goes smooth but I end up with Military time being displayed. I simply want to convet that to 12 hr time and display in a label

Answer (score 1):

Well here is how i ended up fixing it

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:timeZone];  
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatback = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatback setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFormatback setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

NSLog(@"Current Date: %@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
NSLog(@"Sent date: %@",[myPlanData valueForKey:@"planDate"]);
NSDate *aDate =[dateFormat dateFromString:[myPlanData valueForKey:@"planDate"]];
NSLog(@"Converted date is: %@",aDate);
NSString *planDateString = [dateFormatback stringFromDate:aDate];
NSLog(@"The converted date string is: %@",planDateString);

planDateLabel.text=planDateString;
```

Not sure if this is the best or right way to do it but it works!